# IPageRouteModelConvention And Page Links

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm using `IPageRouteModelConvention` to add a global route value:

```
public class TestRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        var selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count;
        for (var i = 0; i < selectorCount; i++)
        {
            var selector = model.Selectors[i];
            model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
            {
                AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                {
                    Order = 0,
                    Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{test}",
                        selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template)
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Hitting a url with `/blah/category` correctly shows my `Category.cshtml` page with "blah" satisfying the `{test}` route value.

However when generating links on said page, its not adding the "blah" via a tag helper:

```
<a class="nav-link" asp-page="category">Category</a>
```

Is there any way of having the tag helper or even `@Url.Page("Category")` include the 'blah'?

Comment: Do you still want a URL of `/Category` to be accessible? It seems that having a combination of both with and without the `{test}` segment is confusing the Razor Pages conventions.

Comment: Interesting, I am using this to help debug: https://github.com/ardalis/AspNetCoreRouteDebugger and the url /Category is accessible, both `/{test}/category` and `/category` are listed. I would prefer it was not accessible.

Comment: If this is just for a single page, you can change the `@page` directive to `@page "{test}/Category"` to use only the one route, I believe - no need for the custom convention class then.

Comment: Its actually an entire app, however your earlier comment lead me to a fix changing `Order=0` to `Order=-1` fixed it. `/category` is still accessible, but I can just return `HttpNotFound` manually. Thanks!